# Jira Rest API Updating an issue fixVersion give error

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to use the JIRA Rest API (version 5) to update an Issue "Fix Version" to set it to a specific version. The current issue I update has some already created bad assignee (the person assigned to it no more exist).

Using the normal Jira web interface, I am able to set the "Fix Version" to the desired value, even if the assignee is wrong.

Using the REST Issue PUT, I received an error:

> assignee: "User 'username' does not exist."

My REST call look like this (using chrome Advanced Rest Client and a C# implementation):

Doing a PUT `http://.../rest/api/2/issue/[issueId]/` Where [issueId] is the Id of my issue.

My payload is:

```
{
    "update" : {
        "fixVersions" : [{
                "set" : [{
                        "name" : "Some Version"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

1. Is it normal that I receive an error on the REST call while I can update the Issue from the web interface ?
2. Is there a way I can update this issue Fix Version by REST without changing the assignee ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to use:

```
client = JIRA::Client.new({:consumer_key => CONSUMER_KEY, :consumer_secret =>                            CONSUMER_SECRET})

 project = client.Project.find('SAMPLEPROJECT')

  project.issues.each do |issue|
    puts "#{issue.id} - #{issue.summary}"
  end

  issue.comments.each {|comment| ... }

 comment = issue.comments.build
 comment.save({'body':'My new comment'})
 comment.delete
```